# How do I solve error "couldn't start tshark" in foren6

Tags: github

I'm trying to use foren6 tool in contiki OS. I'm trying to import a packet trace of a RPL collect network from foren6 examples guide.

While loading pcap files, I'm getting error "could not start tshark". How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

In foren6, file->Preference-> click "Old Tshark" ! and Start.......